# Bootstrap ignores certain media queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I currently have the following scss file with the contents:

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
// Something here
}

/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1198px) {
// Something here
}

/* Large Desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
// Something here
}
```

If I load up `application.css` file in Rails, I get the following:

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  /* Remove gap between nav and content*/
  /* line 120, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss */
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }

  /* Remove any padding from the body */
  /* line 125, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss */
  body {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
  }

  /* line 133, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss */
  .static_pages-controller-home .landing .sign-up {
    display: none;
  }
  /* line 142, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss */
  .static_pages-controller-home .container #students #bulletpoints h2, .static_pages-controller-home .container #students #bulletpoints p {
    text-align: left !important;
  }
}
/* Desktop */
/* Large Desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  /* Remove gap between nav and content*/
  /* line 168, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss */
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }

  /* Bypass left & right padding */
  /* line 186, ../../app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss */
  .static_pages-controller-home .container #students #bulletpoints h2 {
    text-align: left !important;
  }
}
```

Note that in the compiled file, we have the comment `/* Desktop */` but the CSS inside the media query doesn't exist, infact it seems as if the compilation ignored the whole media query. Is there a way to work around this?

My goal is to have some css specific for that width range.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your actual code, my best guess is that you have a gramatical error in the uncompiled file. There's no reason why you can't have some css for the desktop range.

You could try this.

Make a backup of your uncompiled file, then start a new one which just has:

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
// Something here

    font-color{
    color:red;
    }
}

/* Desktop */
@media (min-width: 981px) and (max-width: 1198px) {
// Something here

font-color{
    color:green;
    }
}

/* Large Desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
// Something here

font-color{
    color:blue;
    }
}
```

Compile this and surprise, surprise the font colours will change at different viewpoints.

Once you have this working add the other @media content back in piece by piece so you  can pinpoint the cause.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Old post but maybe I can help someone.

I fix this problem adding this HTML inside `<head>...</head>`

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    ...
</head>
```