# Rails not serving assets in production or staging environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In the process of debugging [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177834/css-styles-not-being-compiled-for-rails-assets), I have tried to run my application in production mode locally and it doesn't serve up any assets. Additionally, I have a **staging** environment in a Heroku application (separate from my production Heroku application) which is also now displaying the HTML without any assets.

To debug, I:

1. Kill the server
2. Clear out tmp/cache/assets
3. Delete public/assets
4. Run `rake assets:precompile`
5. Start up the server `rails s -e production`
6. Visit the page and open up web inspector and when clicking the expand arrow for the application.css link it says `Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:3000/assets/application-e1f3e0c864a153c7iu66f8772a886376.css`
7. Reloading the page does nothing.

**Production.rb**:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

**Staging.rb**:

```
config.cache_classes = true
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

**Application.rb**:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Below is how I link the stylesheet and javascript in *layout/application.html.erb*:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "screen, handheld" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Could you show how you access the assets? Like `= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"`

Comment: What Rack middleware are you using? Switching to thin required me to set `config.assets.compile = true` rather than the default of `false` - but not if I used Passenger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem was that the memory store was set to `config.cache_store = :dalli_store` which was causing errors and setting it to `config.cache_store = :memory_store` resolved it.

Comment: for some reason that doesn't seem like it would be related at all. how is that possible?

Comment: @CourtS: Sprockets will [use the default cache store](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#assets-cache-store) when caching assets in development/production. It defaults to file store.

Answer (score 6):

This is sort of a guess, but doesn't compile assets need to be set to true?

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

and i think you need to compile the assets like this:

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV='production'
```

Comment: Incorrect, with `config.assets.compile = true` all requests for assets in the pipeline are handled by Sprockets directly. Also, specifying the environment doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you try to precompile the assets as i've suggested? Or according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340635/images-and-assets-not-working-in-my-production-server-on-rails-3-1-0, you could try setting `config.serve_static_assets = false`.

Comment: Yes. I've also changed `config.serve_static_assets = false` and the digest url of the assets in web inspector match those of the files in public/assets but it's still saying `get http:localhost:3000/assets/application-e1f3e0c864a153c75866f8772a056376.css 404 (not found)`. I've also restarted the server and hard-refreshed the browser.

Comment: I believe the assets get compiled into the /public directory of your project. Do the files actually exist in that folder?

Comment: Should have `config.serve_static_assets = true` unless you have a separate server serving these assets.