# Rails 4 assets not being served in production on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I'm currently having the exact same problem as described in this post: [Rails not serving assets in production or staging environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206789/rails-not-serving-assets-in-production-or-staging-environments).

I am running Rails 4.0.4 in production environment on Windows 7 (so that could easily be the problem, can't use Linux unfortunately). I have run `rake assets:clobber` to make sure everything is cleaned up and and then `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` and it succeeds without errors or warnings. All the files appear in my public/assets folder and using Windows explorer I can view the text in application.js and application.css, and images display correctly. However when I try to visit localhost:3001/assets/application.js it is blank, same with application.css, and image files come up with an error. I have restarted the server each time after changing settings and precompiling.

When I look at the logs it says the page renders successfully, there are no "No route matches" errors like I have seen in other posts. So the assets are being found, but for some reason they aren't being properly served.

Here is my production.rb:

```
ABC::Application.configure do

    config.cache_classes = true
    config.eager_load = true
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
    config.serve_static_assets = true
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '' }
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
    config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
    config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
    config.assets.compile = false
    config.assets.digest = true

end
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been stuck on this for nearly two days!

Answer (score 0):

Just as I finished typing up this question, I finally came across another post which said the headers were being set but there was no body, which sounded like my problem. They were using nginx and fixed the problem by changing the following:

```
# Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

And seeing as I'm not using either Apache or nginx, I commented out both lines and finally my assets were served. Seems obvious in hindsight but I thought I would post this anyway in case it helps anyone else having the same problem.